Rat-like Creatures that burrow into flesh, as people try to escape a house?
I can't fully remember the entirety of the movie. It was English and it was somewhat retro if memory serves me right. So maybe late 90's early 00's.
To be more specific, they are the size of small ferrets and they aren't seen much. They burrow into the people of the movie if they get too close.
At one point in the movie, I remember that there was a guy with a gun, he had been pushed into a chimney, accidently moving the board blocking it. The creatures burrowed into the guy's head and killed him. Outside it was snowing, like heavy snow, which made it even harder to escape.
As time went on, a man and a woman got away into a car, which the creatures had gotten into as well. The creatures were coming out of the air vents and other parts of the car.
Then the woman got one stuck in her leg if I remember correctly. They ended up stopping by a shop, where he dug the creature out with a knife. They then proceeded to try to kill it in the store. 
I think one of the firsts things to get attacked by these creatures was an orange furry cat. Thats when the people realized what was happening.

Sounds like Tremors (1990) or Tremors 2: Aftershocks (1996)

@AravindSuresh Probably not, the "graboïds" in Tremors are rather huge and do not drill into people's bodies.

Nope, I love the Tremors series.
These creatures lived in the walls and were the size of small ferrets, they might have looked like mole rats with spikes on their body.
